# Countable Complete Metric Space Examples Wanted

Tags: real-analysis

I am rather rusty and am reading Topology by Graham and Greene.  One of the problems refers to a countable complete metric space.  The rationals don't seem to be such a space, because the irrationals are adherent to them and one can form a Cauchy sequence of rationals that converges to an irrational.  Thus, the rationals are not complete.
Could someone please offer an example or two of countable complete metric spaces?

Comment: Discrete $\implies$ complete ...

Comment: Consider countable successor ordinals (order topology, which in this case is metrizable -- in fact, embeddable into the reals, even the rationals), which are compact (hence complete), and spaces homeomorphic to them (e.g. corresponding reversed-order examples).

Comment: Your kind reply is beyond my level of understanding, but thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb N$ and $K = \{0\} \cup \{\frac1n \mathrel\vert n \in \mathbb N\}$ are two simple examples.

It's hard to come up with examples that exhibit "interesting" behaviour because of the following

> **Theorem**
>
> Any complete metric space with no isolated points is uncountable.

The standard proof of this uses the Baire Category Theorem.

Comment: Yes,  I thought of N and K =  (1) U {n/(n+1) {n belongs to N} }